# How to solve $\frac{2}{3}tx+\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{2x-1}+2\sqrt{3-x}=t+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$ where $t=\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $t=\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6}$
>
> then fine the $x$:
>
> $$\frac{2}{3}tx+\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{2x-1}+2\sqrt{3-x}=t+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$$

---

since : $$\sqrt{2x-3} \to 2x-3 \geq 0 \to x\geq\dfrac{3}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{2x-1} \to 2x-1 \geq 0 \to x\geq\dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{3-x} \to 3-x \geq 0 \to x\leq 3$$

So :

$$ \dfrac{3}{2} \leq x \leq 3$$

Now what ?

Comment: $x = 3$ works: $$2t + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} = t + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}$$ clearly.

Comment: @Chris. just x=3 ?

Comment: Can we use the following approach: if the right expression is combination of irrational numbers (square roots): $2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{6}$ then in the left side either $\tfrac{2}{3} x$ is integer or the left-side square roots doesn't give us third-party square roots expressions: when we choose x for such cases?

Answer (score 2):

if you see $d(d(\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{2x-1}+2\sqrt{3-x})/dx)/dx$, you will see that is less than zero from $\frac{3}{2}$ to $3$. So $f = \frac{2}{3}tx + \sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{2x-1}+2\sqrt{3-x} - t - \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{6}$ is convex upward. At $x = \frac{3}{2}$ is zero, at $x = 3$ is zero too. So we have no other roots.

Comment: $d(df/dx)/dx = d(d(\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{2x-1}+2\sqrt{3-x})/dx)/dx = - \frac{1}{(2x-3)^{3/2}}- \frac{1}{(2x-1)^{3/2}}- \frac{1}{(6-2x)^{3/2}}$